# How to merge cell in Excel in this specific way

Tags: excel

Someone who obviously didn't know how to use excel made a very long table in this format:

```
r1   lastname          Description
r2   smith             He had a big
r3   bradley           head and red
r4                     hair with eye
r5                     glasses
```

Where r represents a row and the description describes all two doctors. Is there a way to amalgamate the lastname/description into one big cell like this

```
r1   lastname          Description
r1   smith             He had a big
r1   bradley           head and red
r1                     hair with eye
r1                     glasses
```

Comment: Or you can copy it to some text editor and remove the new line entries using replace option

Comment: The paste in notepad and putting it back into excel works, but I have at least 50 rows of these instances so brute forcing would definitely not be an option!

Answer (score 1):

If it's only a single table and you won't need to keep doing this, I recommend just selecting the whole thing and pasting text-only into word / a text editor. If there's a lot of data in the tables and you need to align everything row by row then you need to give more information about what you have now and what you need it to be.

**Edit on elaboration**

Assuming that (a) a single entry always has the "name" section one row after another without an empty cell, and (b) there is always at least 1 empty cell between names, here's a non-VBA solution:

First create a helper column, starting in C3 and copied down (in C2 just enter TRUE):

```
=and(isblank(C2),not(isblank(c3)))
```

This formula will check whether the current row is NOT BLANK and whether the previous row is BLANK. If that's the case, we can presume that this row starts a new name.

Then create a new "name" column, with the header on D1. The formula starting at D2 and copied down should be:
    =if(C2,A2,D1&if(isblank(CHAR(10)&A2)

As you drag this down, it will either pick up the cell above (the already determined portion of that name), then apply the character for a line break [if that row in column A isn't blank itself], and then add on the new name found on that row in column A - or, if this is a new name, it will start the process again with that row in column A.

The same process can be used in column E, to show the description. Starting in E2, and copied down:

```
=if(C2,B2,E1&if(isblank(B2),"",CHAR(10))&B2)
```

Then create a filter to only show the items which have all the information together. In column F, starting in row 2 and copied down:

```
=if(C3,"Final Row","")
```

Apply a filter to that column, which checks to see if the next row coming up is a new person. If the next row is a new person, the current row contains all the text of the current person.

Comment: Ok let me reformat what it looks like right now and what I want.

Comment: You need to show more about what the data looks like in more than one instance. Solving a problem like this requires knowledge about the uniformity of the data. ie: are there 20 rows like this, and they all start 5 rows after the last one, etc.

Comment: There are many instances like this, and often times have more than 1 or 2 last names. Overall the table has at least 50 instances of this. There is no real pattern, e.g., 2 names then 4 blank rows, it is very sporadic

Comment: Revised based on the assumption that there's always some blank space between the names.